# How to find a not strong element inside of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a paragraph like so:

```
<p>
    <strong>Cost:</strong>
    $1,500 - $10,000 (see below for details)
</p>
```

where I want to select first the `strong` text and then the `not strong` text.

I was trying the following:

```
$('p').not('strong').html()
```

and

```
$('p:not("strong")')
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You were close, but your selector denotes "paragraph tags that are not strong tags"

Comment: Do you want to grab each of the text separately?

Answer (score 5):

If you need p elements that do not has strong in them, then you need to combine `:has` selector as well

```
$('p:not(:has(strong))')
```

for getting the text node text without strong contents:

```
$('p').clone().children().remove().end().text();//returns  $1,500 - $10,000 (see below for details)
```

for getting the strong element text:

```
 $('p strong').text();//return Cost:
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bf7hv3sr/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("p").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var elems = $.parseHTML($("p").html()).filter(function(elem, i) {
  return elem.tagName === "STRONG" 
         || elem.previousSibling !== null 
            && elem.previousSibling.tagName === "STRONG"
});
// `elems[0]`:`STRONG` element , `elems[1]`:`#text` node;
// `$(elems).eq(0)`:jQuery object `$("strong")`,
// `$(elems).eq(1)`:jQuery object `$("text")`
console.log(
  elems[0], elems[1],  
  $(elems).eq(0).text(), $(elems).eq(1).text()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>Cost:</strong>
  $1,500 - $10,000 (see below for details)
</p>
```